# What is the order of excecution of printf(..) parameters?

Tags: c, printf

I want to do something like this `printf("%d,%d",array[c], array[c+1])`, with only one variable that increases in every iteration. I wrote the following code, and I expected "1,2" to stdout, I was wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c = 1;
    printf("%d,%d",c++,c++); /* 2,1 */
    //printf("%d,%d",c,c++);   /* 2,1 */
    //printf("%d,%d",c++,c);   /* 1,2 */
}
```

If I try doing `printf("%d,%d",c++,c)` and  `printf("%d,%d",c,c++)`, I can see that there is no defined order of execution of the "c++" statements.

Could somebody explain how the code I wrote compiles to ? And why and how does it change according to the position of the "c++" statements.

Comment: The order is unspecified. But this is also an undefined behavior to `c++` twice without sequence point in between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the arguments in a function call is unspecified,
and there is no sequence point between the evaluation of these expressions. This means that - if one expression alters as a side effect an object (like the value of `c`) which is also accessed by another expression - it is unpredictable what the outcome of these expressions will be. For that reason, the language defines such cases as *undefined behaviour* (cf., for example, [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p2) online C standard draft):

> **6.5 Expressions**
>
> 2.) If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to
>   either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
>   computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
>   undefined. ...

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. As ++ operator has side effects - it is undefined behavior to make two side effects inside one expression (function call).

Answer (score 1):

The order in which arguments to a function are evaluated is not defined by the C standard. The order in which arguments are *passed* to a function are normally defined by the calling convention, though that still leaves the order of evaluation up to the compiler.

For example, if you have a calling convention where parameters are pushed on the stack right to left (this is ubiquitous on x86-32), the assembly generated for `printf("%d %d", c, c++);` might look like:

```
push eax ; arg 3
push edx ; arg 2
push offset format_string
call _printf
add esp, 12
```

However, we still can't reason about which order `eax` and `edx` were populated with the value of `c` and `c++`.